# how to get data inside div element that doesnt have an ID using soup object

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with BeautifulSoup and in a website

> "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/",

I have a div element without ID and I want to get the contents inside the Div and store it in a variable

```
Eg: "Last updated: April 03, 2020, 03:34 GMT"
```

This is the div element:

```
<div style="font-size:13px; color:#999; text-align:center">Last updated: April 03, 2020, 03:34 GMT</div>
```

Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: <div style="font-size:13px; color:#999; text-align:center">Last updated: April 03, 2020, 03:34 GMT</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regular expression` **re** and search the div with text `Last updated`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
r=requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
strlastdate=soup.find('div',text=re.compile("Last updated")).text
print(strlastdate)
```

**Output**:

```
Last updated: April 03, 2020, 20:35 GMT
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well. Thanks a lot for your response. Learning new things daily.... and you are awesome